# Define n functions at once in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Suppose I want to do the following:

```
(loop for i from 1 to n do
    (defun ith(lst)
        (nth i lst)))
```

Apparently what I really want to do is the following:

```
(defun 1th(lst)(nth 1 lst))
(defun 2th(lst)(nth 2 lst))
(defun 3th(lst)(nth 3 lst))
(defun 4th(lst)(nth 4 lst))
......
(defun 100th(lst)(nth 100 lst))
```

How can I make that?

Comment: Does this have any practical use? `nth` is O(n) on the number given, so, once you get above 10 or so, it gets really expensive to call.

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: This is only an example of what I want to do: namely replace those "i" in ith by 1, 2, 3, ...

Comment: I think that generically creating global(ly special) names in this way is an anti-pattern.  It is very obvious that you are putting a function parameter into its _name_.

Comment: @Svante: Good point. I was just trying to find an example...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go. Note that `|1th|` would return the second value:

```
(defmacro make-nths (n)
  `(progn
     ,@(loop for i from 1 to n
             collecting `(defun ,(intern (format nil "~ath" i)) (list)
                           (nth ,i list)))))
```

As Xach pointed out in the comments, `macrolet` might be preferable here, since you do not really need a globally defined macro:

```
(macrolet ((make-nths (n)
             `(progn
                ,@(loop for i from 1 to n
                        collect `(defun ,(intern (format nil "~ath" i)) (list)
                                   (nth ,i list))))))
  (make-nths 3)) ; choose n here
```

Finally, here is a working version of ninjaaa's non-macro solution:

```
(loop for i from 1 to 3 ; choose n here
      do (let ((i i))   ; introduce new bindings for each iteration
           (setf (symbol-function (intern (format nil "~ath" i)))
                 (lambda (list) (nth i list)))))
```

Comment: If you wanted to have `1st`, `2nd` etc. rather than `1th`, `2th`, you can add a clause `for suffix = (subset (format nil "~:R" i) -2)` clause after the existing `for` clause, and change the existing `format` call with `(format nil "~A~A" i suffix)`.

Comment: If the macro is used only once and need not be globally defined, `macrolet` can be more suitable.

Comment: Xach: Yes, I have added a `macrolet` example.

Comment: Excellent, I know what macrolet is for now. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(loop for i from 1 to n do
   (setf (symbol-function (intern (format nil "~dth" i)))
     #'(lambda (lst) (nth i lst))))
```

Comment: This looks as if it could work, but did you actually test it? (Hint: `loop` doesn't introduce a new binding for each iteration)